# How can we get the Salesforce Rest/SOAP end point

Tags: rest, soap, salesforce

I am doing a POC where I need to push data to Salesforce using REST/SOAP API.

I have launched a salesforce instance (30 days trial version) and I am able to create records over there i.e `Accounts , Leads` etc.

Now I need to create records using POST but I am not able to find END points for my salesforce

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to switch from using a 30 day trial to using a developer edition org.https://developer.salesforce.com/signup

Answer (score 2):

The [REST docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) go into details about using the endpoints and the [user info](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm) REST API has details on the endpoints.